# How do I calculate the size of a virtual page in a system?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

Given a virtual memory system which utilises a 32-bit virtual address. 
A page table that takes 1 MiB of memory per process.
Each PTE(page table entry requires 4 bytes. 
The system has a total of 256 Megabytes of memory available.

I understand that a Page table is essentially a list of entries(PTE) that provide a mapping of the virtual addresses to a physical address.

I need to calculate the size of each virtual page. But I have no clue how.
So far all I've got is 2^20(page-table size)/2^2(PTE size)=2^18 this gives me the total amount of entries I can have in a page table. I'm not even sure if this is useful to find the size of each virtual page.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding in how these metrics relate to the size of a virtual page.

Edit: I've found out the size of the page is determined by the following.
A virtual address consists of bits for a page pointer and an offset.
The last bits of the virtual address are called the offset which is the location difference between the byte address you want and the start of the page. You require enough bits in the offset to be able to get to any byte in the page.For a 4K page you require (4K == (4 * 1024) == 4096 == 212 ==) 12 bits of offset.

The page pointer can be determined by the number of entries in the table. This was simply my formula from before 2^20(page-table size)/2^2(PTE size)=2^18 entries. Which means I have 18 bits being used in my virtual address for my page pointer. I can determine the offset by 2^32(virtual address size)/2^18 which gives me 2^14. Therefore my page size for my virtual address is 2^14 or 16KiB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as you describe is under-specified.  You need to know the width of the page offset field within the virtual address (or, how many levels of indirection the VM system is using).  For example, (as in ONE of the modes that x86 system uses), if you have two levels of indirection, then you will have 10x2 bits used for levels of indirection and remaining 12 bits for offset within the page. That gives you a page size (= frame size) of 4KB.

If you instead use one level of indirection (as ANOTHER x86 mode allowed, but is found less often), then you can have a division of 10 bits for the only level of indirection and remaining 22 bits as offset within the page.  That gives a page size of 4MB.

You see above that same 32 bit virtual address can follow different levels of indirection for paging and end up with different page sizes.

Page offset size in the virtual address determines the page size.

Comment: I have determined the answer to be 2^14 as confirmed by my lecturer. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer under those fact. You have the page table entry is 32 bits. That puts a theoretical upper bound on the page size as 2^32. However, some bits are going to used for control so the size will be smaller.

The 1MB size of of the page table and 32-bit virtual address facts are irrelevant to the page size.

Comment: I have determined the answer to be 2^14 as confirmed by my lecturer. Please see my edit.

Comment: The problem is your fact do not give the number of page table entries. Your lecturer is feeding you some academic nonsense that has no reality, sorry. The size of a page table is not [necessarily] "2^20(page-table size)/2^2(PTE size)=2^18 entries."